# Retreiving Google Chrome passwords

Tags: passwords, databases

While retrieving Google Chrome passwords on macOS, I've noticed that the passwords all come up as the same thing (something along the lines of): `Vi??M!4NNn`. How I retreived them was with the following (as a non-admin):

```
cd "users/user/library/application support/google/chrome/default"
sqlite3 "Login Data"
sqlite3> .output chrome-passwords.txt
sqlite3> select origin_url, username_values, password_value from logins;
```

Even if I run as root and pull the passwords I get the same thing, what is causing this and how can I retrieve them correctly?

Comment: It will be something very wrong if Chrome allow you to skim through the sqlite data and get the password in plaintext without some authentication API to decode the stuff.

Comment: @mootmoot This is true, however, they use to store their passwords in plaintext. Would the decryption key by chance be in my keychain?

Comment: Good luck ;-) 

https://github.com/adnan-alhomssi/chrome-passwords

Comment: Seems there is already answer here.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40884/is-saving-passwords-in-chrome-as-safe-as-using-lastpass-if-you-leave-it-signed-i/40887#40887

Comment: @mootmoot "It will be something very wrong if Chrome allow you to skim through the sqlite data and get the password in plaintext" Well, how should they protect locally stored passwords (without a master password model)?

Comment: @Arminius you can read the github link I gave.

Comment: Not only is that measure platform-specific, but it also isn't much safer than storing the passwords in plain text straight away.

Comment: @Arminius .. Well,  I quit using chrome locally stored password for quite some time ;-)

Comment: @mootmoot the program you sent is specifically for Windows systems

Comment: That's why I put it as comment, not an answer. Anyway : Try your luck here  
https://github.com/manwhoami/OSXChromeDecrypt

Comment: I figured out how to get them done actually

Comment: @CertifcateJunky, it's OK to answer your own question. This will help other people.

Comment: @Arminius excellent point. And even a master password would only provide a slight delay if malware is running locally as the devs have argued: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1397

Comment: @NeilSmithline I will, just don't have time at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I figured it out and said I would post an answer.

The reason that the passwords showed up like they did is because they are encrypted with a `pbkdf2` key that is stored in a specific keychain location (usually having the name 'Chrome' in it). To find this key you can execute the command `security find-generic-password -wa 'Chrome'` as an administrator and it should pull the key for you.

Once you have the key, in order to decrypt the you would need to;

- Generate the IV (`python -c 'import sys;sys.stdout.write("20" * 16)'`
- Get the salt (110% chance it's `saltysalt`)
- Encrypt the found key using `pbkdf2_hmac` grabbing the first 16 characters and hexlify the encrypted key (`python -c 'import binascii;import hashlib;key=hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha1","<KEY>",b"saltysalt",1003)[:16];print binascii.hexlify(key)`)
- Base64 encode the encrypted password and remove the first three characters (`python -c 'import base64;print base64.b64encode("ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD")[3:]'`)
- Decrypt the encryption with the following command: `openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-128-cbc -v <IV> '<HEX KEY>' -K '<BASE64 ENCODED PASSWORD>'`.

Luckily for you, I created a simple python function to return the same thing:

```
import base64
import binascii
import subprocess
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac


def decrypt(encrypted, key):
    iv = ''.join(('20', ) * 16)
    key = pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', key, b'saltysalt', 1003)[:16]

    hex_key = binascii.hexlify(key)
    hex_enc_password = base64.b64encode(encrypted[3:])
    try:
        decrypted = subprocess.check_output(
            "openssl enc -base64 -d "
            "-aes-128-cbc -iv '{}' -K {} <<< "
            "{} 2>/dev/null".format(iv, hex_key, hex_enc_password),
            shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        decrypted = "n/a"

    return decrypted
```

Please note, in order for the to work successfully, you have to have the administrative credentials for the computer you're running this on.

Comment: Mh I found that in some programs on windows they use: